# Is Facebook Ad Manager the right tool to create and edit ads?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use the Facebook Ad Manager tool for iOS to create and edit ads.   I am on iOS 9 on a 32-bit iPad.  I am finding the tool is so glitchy that I can't get through two screens without it crashing and dumping meto the iOS home screen.  It is impossible to get any work done.

Is it just widely known that this tool is useless, and if so, what other tools do people use to be effective?

... or is my system somehow corrupt?  I have Facebook Page app and Ads Manager but not the Facebook app proper, does that matter?

I also have a great many ads from 2013-16 in the system, and they have obsolete ad settings that are not compatible with the current platform.  Is it possible these are glitching Ads Manager?